# can't get regexner example to work

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp

I am trying the example from the command line as described in the below page.
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner/

The command I tried was

```
java  -mx1g -cp '*' edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner' -file sampleText.txt -regexner.mapping jg-regexner.txt
```

Here I have taken care to use proper tab separation in the regexner mapping file 'jg-regexner' as follows:

```
Bachelor of (Arts|Laws|Science|Engineering) DEGREE
Lalor    LOCATION   PERSON
Labor    ORGANIZATION
```

but still getting the same result where Lalor is still marked as a person

Anyone else faced a similar issue?

Comment: I had missed adding the regexner in the pipeline
Issue resolved.